# Is there a way to get the users home screen background on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'd like to use the same background for my app as the users home screen's background. Is there a way to get it without user input?

Answer (score 0):

There was a way to do that with private API (calling `UIGetScreenImage()` from background) but removed at iOS 7.